# RDBMS (MySQL) logic question. How to join multiple "FRIENDS"

Tags: database-design, mysql, relational-database, rdbms

so this is a logic question as to creating the proper relationships in a MySQL database.

What logic would you choose for the following scenario?

This is a back-end for an app where people can have friends they can interact with, or "Add" if you will to their own "Network" for lack of better terms.

So, for example, should I have a "MyFriends" table where, for example, the "MyFriend.ID" column is identical to perhaps the "User.ID" of the person that initiated the connection? And have a subsequent column called "Friends" where the "User.ID" of everyone you "Added" to your "Network" is inserted?

Or do you have alternate suggestions as to create the Relationships necessary for the "Friends" to be connected inside each owns "Network"?

Comment: Have you looked at [Storing Friends in Database for Social Network](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6618701/289086) (other results for [friends mysql](http://stackexchange.com/search?q=friends+mysql) across Stack Exchange)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd have one table for Users and a second table for Relationships.

The Relationship table would have 2 foreign keys, both pointing back to records in the User table.

Here's a rough diagram:

```
+------------------+         +------------------------+
| User             |         | Relationship           |
|------------------|         |------------------------|
| UserPK  (int)    |         | RelationshipPK (int)   |
| ...              |<--------+ User1FK        (int)   |
|                  |<--------+ User2FK        (int)   |
|                  |         |                        |
|                  |         |                        |
|                  |         |                        |
|                  |         |                        |
+------------------+         +------------------------+
```

The Relationship table is technically the middle table in a many to many relationship.

Here's an example.  Note the diagram shows 2 records from the `USER` table:

```
+------------------+         +------------------------+      +------------------+
| User             |         | Relationship           |      | User             |
|------------------|         |------------------------|      |------------------|
| UserPK:     1    |         | RelationshipPK   100   |      | UserPK:     2    |
| Name:   ALICE    |<--------+ User1FK            1   |      | Name:     BOB    |
|                  |         | User2FK            2   +----->|                  |
|                  |         |                        |      |                  |
|                  |         |                        |      |                  |
|                  |         |                        |      |                  |
|                  |         |                        |      |                  |
+------------------+         +------------------------+      +------------------+
```

We have 3 records in the database: a `USER` record for Alice, a `USER` record for Bob, and a `RELATIONSHIP` record showing that Alice and Bob know each other.

You'll probably want to add additional fields to these tables.  For example, is the relationship "friends", "co workers", "family", etc.

If Alice is a friend of Bob and Bob is a friend of Alice (i.e., a symmetrical relationship), it might be easiest to just have two records in the relationship table (User1FK:Alice, User2FK:Bob and User1FK:Bob, User2FK:Alice).  That would make certain queries easier.

Comment: If the relationship is symmetrical, would you insert two 'Relationship' records to avoid `where User1FK = 1 or User2FK = 1` type queries?

Comment: @MichaelT Probably.  It would result in more records than strictly necessary but would make querying for "my friends" easier.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer. Would you just elaborate in the comments a bit more about the "Symmetrical" aspect? Yes, if a user has "Accepted" your invitation, you would both be added to each others "Relationship"

Comment: The short answer is "yes".  I've updated the answer a bit.